# Compilation error with power of ten in old code

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-11-alexandria

I am experiencing an issue with an old Delphi program (I can read comments saying "last edit 21/09/1992")

When I load the project with the latest Delphi 11, there are compilation errors:

```pascal
value := 5.E-3
```

> E2003 Error: Identifier undeclared 'E' line xxx

I believe it means 5 * 10<sup>-3</sup>, ie 0.005.

To make this line compile, I removed the dot, I now have

```pascal
value := 5E-3
```

Unfortunately, the test using this line does not execute properly, since it is the only modification I made, and the code is not commented (except some dates from last centurys). I wonder if my fix was correct by removing the dot.

Has there been a syntax modification in the language that is documented (Delphi 7 to Delphi 11)?

I have hundreds of these "5.E-3" and I want to be certain my correction is correct.

Comment: I'm surprised to learn that 5.E-3 has ever been accepted by the Delphi compiler. (Are you sure it does compile in old Delphi versions? But then again, I didn't use Delphi in 1992. In fact, no-one did, since the first version of Delphi was released in 1995.) The only reasonable guess is that the author does indeed mean 5.0E-3, that is, 5E-3. Some languages do support this syntax (like my own Algosim!). Maybe this includes some pre-Delphi Pascal implementation.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, it was probably originaly written in Pascal.
The oldest comment i found was 1986, and the most recent was 2011.
Several generations of developpers have been working on this code, none of then knew how to write comments.
I will use step by step execution to try to understand, but my eyes are bleeding in advance.

Comment: Could it be you run into problems because you have System.SysUtils in the `uses` list? System.SysUtils declares a `record helper for Double` and with the trailing dot the compiler might think `E` is supposed to be a member of this `record helper`. And yes, absent of record helpers `5E-3`, `5.E-3`, and `5.0E-3` are all valid syntax and identical in value.

Comment: Delphi's supported syntax is documented: [Floating Point Constants](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Floating_Point_Constants)

Comment: Syntax works in D4 and D5 both for double and real type.

Comment: And also in D6.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how old your code is it may well originate from Turbo Pascal.

Turbo Pascal did not support floating point numbers like modern Delphi does so I'm guessing that the type of your `value` variable is `Real`. But that is not the same type as [System.Real](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Athens/en/System.Real).

Instead in Turbo Pascal `real` type had different data structure as you can read at [Turbo Pascal Real](https://moddingwiki.shikadi.net/wiki/Turbo_Pascal_Real).

This means that even if you manage to make suitable changes in your code so that all those numbers are represented with correct scientific notation that Delphi accepts the actual value of the number may not be the same as it was in Turbo Pascal due to difference of how Turbo Pascal and modern Delphi versions are treating `Real` type.

Comment: Just compiled an example with TP7. Both real and double works in TP7 (enable floating point hardware for the double).